# Handle multiple registers with Vue and API endpoint

Tags: database, web-services, vue.js, vuex

I have an application with clients stored in a database, the quantity of clients is variable, currently I have 2 hundreds but I could have 2 million. Also I have a web service that queries this database and exposes an endpoint. To display those clients I have a simple Vue application that shows a form filled with one client at time and next and previous buttons to get more clients.

The point is, what is the best approach to get clients from my database to Vue:

- Should I **get all clients from database** and store them in vuex? With this options, next and prev buttons just take one or other index from stored array.
- Should I just **get the current client** I'm displaying and store it in vuex? With this options, next and prev buttons call the endpoint requesting the next or prev client.
- Maybe should make a **chunk loading** and store n clients in vuex? With this option, next and prev buttons search the client in the array, if the index is out of bounds should call the endpoint requesting the n next or previous clients and will store them in the vuex array.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty trivial; if your data is getting too big, just think of a way to chunk or paginate it and load new chunks when you need them.

Comment: Not one at a time if you'll browse them like that. Better to reduce the amount of server calls and make the app feel more responsive.  If paginating, ~25-100+ should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Chunk loading would be an ideal situation where users need not for wait for client load to complete on click of 'next' to view the next client and also not bloating the browser storage with a large number of unused client details.

A slightly modified chunk loading approach would be to always fetch the next and previous client details when loading particular client details so that users need not wait for network call to complete when going to the next client.

eg when fetching client 2 - fetch 1,3. 
when user clicks next directly render 3rd client details from the store but fetch client 4 in the background so that next and previous click is smooth.